# snappy packages and loopback devices and managing mounts

Tags: mount, snap

My understanding is that Ubuntu is moving in the direction of relying more on snappy packages.  And, my understanding is that each snappy package will be mounted as a loopback device.  Soooooo......  If I have 35 snappy packages installed, I'd have 35 loopback devices mounted.

Isn't something like this going to make managing drives a lot harder if using tools like gnome-disk-utility?  Won't the list of drives be clogged up by having all those loopback devices showing up?  Or is my understanding of this all wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Good question and as most of the time, for those "good questions" there is a yes and no answer.

Yes it will make it harder to sift through a simple `mount` output, yet a simple `mount | grep -v "/snap/*"` will reduce this by far - probably more clever expressions will do even more.

As you can see in the picture below, `gnome-disk-utility` puts the loop-devices (in the picture "Schleifengerät") at the end of the list of "devices", so yes it will get crowded, but on the lower end of the list, so it should not hamper you too much.

[image]

Yet I believe kinks like these can be easily ironed out, and most likely will.